# How to get how many byte has upload so far?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

My upload method as below:

```
private void upload(String Server, String FilePath, String SavePath, String NewName) {
String end = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
try {
URL url = new URL(ActionUrl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/*");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
ds = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);
ds.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;" + "name=\"folder\"" + end + end);
ds.write(SavePath.getBytes("UTF-8"));
ds.writeBytes(end);
ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);
ds.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;" + "name=\"Filedata\"; filename=\"");
ds.write(NewName.getBytes("UTF-8"));
ds.writeBytes("\"" + end);
ds.writeBytes(end);

FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int length = -1;
while((length = fStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
ds.write(buffer, 0, length);
}       
ds.writeBytes(end);
ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + end);

fStream.close();
ds.flush();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
int ch;
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
while((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
b.append((char)ch);
}
System.out.println("UPLOAD" + "SUCCESS");
ds.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I want to show the progress bar.
But I did not know how much byte has be upload so far.
Any methods to get the number of bytes which has be upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it how to do this in java.So try your luck with android and let me know.Follow below link -------------
[Uploading code](https://qooxdoo-contrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/qooxdoo-contrib/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib/UploadJavaApplet/trunk/uploadApplet/java/src/dndapplet/applet/DNDApplet.java)

and this is some theory explanation

[SecondLink](http://panyasan.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/open-source-drag-drop-upload-java-applet-for-websites/)